# Shader problems: Heroes of Newerth

Tags: drivers, 11.04, graphics, games, visual-artifacts

I am getting strange "artifacts" in 3D games such as Heroes of Newerth.

I have Ubuntu Natty,
I am **not** running the propriety graphics driver as I am using GNOME3 and the driver does not work well.

I have a [Dell Inspiron 1545](http://www.dell.com/us/p/inspiron-15/pd).

[image: Image showing artifacts in heroes of newerth]

The artifacts are almost tolerable, but the game quite often also crashes, with no warning or error.

How can I fix this, or (if it's a bug) how do I report this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the non Proprietary Drivers dont work well with games

And on how to report a bug, Take a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/5126/17722) answer